# Can't auto-size row height to image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm building a page with react-bootstrap and wanted to place an image as a background for one of the rows that I have in my grid. The  height of the img is 1237.5px and it's placed in the `Col` Component. If I change the height explicitly to e.g. `height: 25%`, the image takes 25% of the height of the `Row` component but the `Row` component is still 1237.5px high.

I'd like `Row` component to have `height: 30%` of the desktop screen. It should be responsive and on mobile it should take the whole screen height.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UpperBar></UpperBar>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row >
          <Col xs={12} md={12} >
            <FirstBlock></FirstBlock>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>1 of 2</Col>
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>2 of 2</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>1 of 2</Col>
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>2 of 2</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div >
  );
}

function FirstBlock() {
    return (
        <Image src={discolight} alt="first" style={{height: "25%", width: "100%"}}></Image>
    );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4IfE.jpg)